# How can I pass a read only collection to a blazor component?

Tags: blazor

I have created a simple Blazor component (.NET Core 3.1, Blazor server apps) with a public parameter:

```
    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Resource> Services { get; set; }
```

I fill this parameter from a **.cshtml** page:

```
    <component type="typeof(ActivityView)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-Services="Model.Services" />
```

The model property has the same type:

```
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Resource> Services { get; set; }
```

When the instance of services is a **ReadOnlyCollection(Resource)**, the blazor page directly runs into the following error on the client side:

> Error: The list of component records is not valid. (blazor.server.js:15)

When the instance of services is a **List(Resource)**, the blazor page works perfectly fine.

To clarify this:

```
    Services = someList.ToList(); // works.
    Services = someList.ToList().AsReadOnly(); // does not work
```

I could not find anything about supported objects passed to Blazor components as parameter in the MSDN documentation. Howevery, I noticed classes without a parameterless constructor seem to be not supported as well. Resource must have a parameterless constructor; otherwise I run into the same error.

Does anyone know the reason here? The object is not used for data binding. It is only used to fill a dropdown list with values. Is this a known Blazor issue in 3.1?

Comment: Are you sure of : `param-Services="Model.Services"` ? It should be `Services="@Model.Services"` I guess

Comment: Adding the @ does not change anything. Still works with a list object. Still does not work with a ReadOnlyCollection object.

Comment: Why do you use `<component` instead of your component tag `<ActivityView` ?

Comment: The component is included into a normal razor page (.cshtml).

Comment: It's confusing, I edited your question

Comment: May I ask why you use .cshtml instead of .razor?

Comment: Because it is a regular web application, which should include some isolated blazor components. In this example blazor replaced JS componentens.

Comment: @tobi did you ever figure this out, I'm having similar problems.

Comment: @Chris: I did not solve this exact problem, but I understood why it does not work. When you pass the model to a component, the object is not directly given to the component, but instead it is kind of re-created by the component. Think about the old entity framework requiring an IList for collections to add items to the collection. And probably, here we have the same.

However, I changed my architecture anyway. The parameters in components should not be complex objects. It should be a parameter allowing the component to query data for themself. So just inject data access into the component.